# FIxing decimal places during string conversion in Java

Tags: java, string, double

I have some text that has both strings and numbers.

I parse the input and do some computation with the numbers.

I convert the number back to a string via `Double.toString(number)`.

Later I print a `StringBuilder` string that has all the individuals lines of text and calculated numbers appended. I just print using `System.out.println("%s", appended_string)`.

Now when I append to the `StringBuilder` a string that was converted from a `double`, I want it to have specific number of decimal places so that when I print the whole thing at the end it prints with the specified numbers of decimals.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Yes. A bit of string parsing and storing the length. If you need me to, I can write out a small example.

Comment: @Compass. Nevermind I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has a similar question in the future this worked,

```
String formattedString;
formattedString = String.format("%.2f", number);
```

The specifier here is for two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need more control, you could also look into the [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and [`DecmialFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). These allow for greater control in your formatting, than when just using `String#format`.